# v-model on input change is heavy on performance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I have a page rendering a v-list based on an array like so :

```
<v-list-tile v-for="item in array">
{{item}}
</v-list-tile>
```

and a dialog with a v-text-field :

```
<v-dialog>
    <v-text-field v-model="myInput">
    </v-text-field>
</v-dialog>
```

For now it's pretty normal. 
But with a performance test, I saw that for every event triggered by a change on myInput model (like a key press) the v-for is also triggered re-rendering the list when they are actually not related.

On my huge array, it's a serious problem and make the UI really laggy. I think it's a normal behavior for a vuejs application, but I was wondering if I could precisely tell wish element to check for re-rendering.

I tried some v-if statements but it didn't do the trick.

I hope that there is an answer to that, i guess i'm missing something.

If you want to **test** what i'm talking about here is a ready to go html file, please debug it with your debug console, you will see a *[vue warn]* message of the duplicated key attesting of the fact that the v-for is indeed called for every key press.

Imagine now if the array (here items) is way bigger than that, and wrapped into complex components, making that call is just too heavy on performance when we are just aiming to change the "myInput" value.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{data}}
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in items" :key="item">
                {{ item.message }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input v-model="data"></input>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
            data: '',
            items: [{
                    message: 'Foo'
                },
                {
                    message: 'Bar'
                }
            ]
        })
    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: is the dialog inside the list?

Comment: @dandavis It's not.

Comment: maybe try to use v-bind instead v-model. For v-bind you can precise on whivh type of event you want to update field

Comment: Works ok for me, how do you messure the "performance" ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try using .lazy modifier to sync after change events.</strike>

`<input v-model.lazy="data"></input>`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy

### EDIT

@IVO GELOV is right, when a component changes, this re-render. The solution is split your component into several child components.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

This is a code using slots to make it look like your example.

> HTML

```
    <div id="app">
   <new-component>
     <ul>
       <li v-for="item in items" :key="item">
         {{ item.message }}
       </li>       
     </ul>    
   </new-component>
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
    Vue.component('new-component', {
  data: () => {
    return {
      data: ''
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>{{ data }}</div>
      <slot></slot>
      <input v-model="data"></input>
    </div>`
})

new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({            
            items: [{
                    message: 'Foo'
                },
                {
                    message: 'Bar'
                }
            ]
        })
    })
```

Comment: I dont know if anyone noticed this, but the number of warnings follow a formula.

`warning_errors = array.length + (array.length - 1)`

I'll find a most satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a codepen showing the inner loop in its own component

[Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/keyboardSmasher/pen/BEjjrO?editors=1111)

I've added `Date.now()` after `items[x].message` list items to show when the list is being rerendered.

In case codepen ever goes down:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        Main vue: {{data}}
        <loop-component :data="loopdata"></loop-component>
        <input v-model="data"></input>
        <input v-model="loopdata"></input>
    </div>
<script>
Vue.component('loop-component', {
    props: ['data'],
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {message: 'Foo'},
                {message: 'Bar'}
            ]
        }
    },
    template: `
<div>
Loop component: {{ data }}
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    {{ item.message + ' Date.now(): ' + Date.now() }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
`
});

let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        data: '',
        'loopdata': '',
        items: [
            {message: 'Foo'},
            {message: 'Bar'},
        ]
    }),
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Vue 2.0+ whenever a change is detected - the whole component is re-rendered. If you want to avoid that - split your component into several child components.

Your example does not prove your point - the fact that there is a warning about duplicate keys inside the `v-for` does not mean that `v-for` is re-evaluated on each keypress. To confirm my statement - just change your code like this:

```
<li v-for="(item,idx) in items" :key="idx">
```

Now there is no warning.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. Hiding the error, but not solving the performance issue. It's not about the warning...

Comment: So your example is not relevant to your question/complain. And you seem to ignore my advice to split the component into child components - e.g. one component for the INPUT and another component for the `v-list`.